# Python dateparser - Set day to '00' when not found

Tags: python

```
import dateparser

date1 = dateparser.parse('May, 2015')

print date
> 2015-05-11 00:00:00
```

I would like to set the day to '00' if not found, like it doest with time, since it was not found and '11' was guessed from the current day.

Comment: From the docs of `dateparser`, it is not possible to set it to "00" , since its not a valid representation of a day. 

However the lib allows you to change the default from `Current` to `first` day or the `last` day of the month.  Will that work ?

Comment: @Chinmay Yeah better the first day of the month than a total random one! Where I see how to set it to '01' as default?

Comment: You can use the `settings` field, something like this :

`dateparser.parse('May 2015', settings={"PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH": "first"})`

Comment: @Chinmay Perfect thank you! Can you post it as answer so I can check it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of `dateparser`,  you won't be able to set the day to "0" or any other number outside 1-31.

But the lib provides a way to change the default from `current` day to `first` or `last`day.

You can use the `settings` field, something like this :

`dateparser.parse('May 2015', settings={"PREFER_DAY_OF_MONTH": "first"})`